# Cassandra API JMX server thread

Tags: multithreading, service, cassandra, jmx

In cassandra api which class starts JMX Server thread....?

Is it StandardMBean or StorageService...?

functionality of cassandra wrapper.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM starts JMX services automatically, Cassandra just registers MBeans for different services, which automatically results in them being exposed through JMX.